# Ionic 4 with Angular Material 2

Tags: angular-material2, angular6, ionic4

I have my angular material imported in to my Ionic 4 application. I have also updated the styles within the angular.json file to point my style.css for the import of @import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css'; I have a mat-button object displaying on the screen. The css does not display for the button or show up in the console. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the code that you have written for the button?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by installing the new 4.0.0 Ionic Beta which uses the Angular framework more than the Ionic 3. The Ionic 4 is still in beta however if you know Angular, then you are in luck.